# Review with both Visual Studio and Flash Builder (Eclipse) support

Tags: eclipse, flash, code-review, visual-studio

Our project works with Visual Studio 2010 and Flash Builder 6 (Eclipse) with SVN version control. We are looking for a single review tool which can be used within the IDE itself and that works (through plug-ins) for both the IDEs mentioned above. Any suggestion on a such a review tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Collaborator](http://smartbear.com/product/collaborator/specifications/) has clients for both

- Eclipse
- Visual studio.

It also integrates with Subversion.  I used when working for a former employer